# Calculation of expectation from minimum and maximum probability

Tags: probability

The probability of getting minimum  and maximum number of heads after tossing a coin $N$ times is $P_{min}$ and $P_{max}$ respectively. What is the expected number of heads after tossing the same coin $N$ times?

Comment: Please clarify:  If $P_\min$ or $P_\max$ is supposed to be a distribution of  probabilities for min or max coing from $0$ to $N$, then the probelm is tricial, since $p_\min(0)$ alone determines the probability of heads in a single toss.  If this is not what you mean, then what do you mean?

Comment: We don't know the minimum and the maximum number of heads in that experiment. So, we can not assume that it is $0$ and $N$.